# applet starting with 23 secs of white screen

Tags: java, swing, applet, init

I'm going to finish writing a java applet, which uses swing.

I deployed it to my website, but **after the applet finishes loading** (The cup of coffee), the applet shows blank white screen for 23 more seconds.

The applet is deployed here: 
http://www.nispahit.com/applet-2

I read it could be an init problem (that init() of the applet takes a long time). So, I removed everything from init() :

```
@Override
public void init(){     
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "hello");
}
```

Unfortunately it didn't help.
Does someone have an idea as to why it takes 23 more seconds to applet to load with this white screen **after** loading the cup of coffee? (The blank screen will make users think there is a problem...)

A possible solution can be showing the users a message they have to wait instead the white screen - but I don't know how can I do even that...

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**Edit:**
2 more things:

1. When I execute it locally from an html file on my computer, it works just fine (no white screen.
2. I use 2 jar files (because I have to use log4j). I tried switching their order in the html file - didn't help. Maybe the problem is somehow related to it?

Comment: what is inside `initApplet()`?

Comment: [Profile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) to be sure.

Comment: @SeniorJD, I tried to remove all the init() content. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in the JApplet class, I had a member of the type Logger (initialized there).

Apperantly the members (and static members) of the applet are initializing **before** the applet is shown (it's reasonable).
The Logger initialization was very long, and that's why I had the white screen.

If someone run to the same problem, I would check the members of the classes, try to initialize them in the init() method instead on the declaration line.